# Adding id to MVC form input

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this HTML input in a asp.net MVC page:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("Submission.FirstName", null, new { @class = "fname title" })%>
```

How can I add an **id** to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple

```
<%=Html.TextBox("Submission.FirstName", null, new { @class = "fname title", id = "my-id-here" })%>
```

After that you will see the id in the html markup after it will be rendered

Answer (score 1):

The id will be set using the name you supply. In this case the id will be "Submission_FirstName".

Comment: Sorry, but this description is doing little to help me understand the syntax of how this is done.

Comment: @cinqoTimo, You pretty much shouldn't as the framework does it for you by convention. But if you find a case where you need to you can do as tugberk suggested and that will override the convention.

Comment: you are right. not exactly it is the case but in my sample, I am hardcoding it. this would be nice ; <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Model.MyField, new { @class = "fname title" }) %>